# Do we know of any pagan creation myths that also feature a creation week?

Tags: creation

Is the creation week an introduction by Abrahamic religions, or are there other known religions that also have, as part of their creation myths, a creation week (not necessarily of 7 days)? I've googled this question but only got results discussing the creation week in Genesis.

Comment: This might be a wasted bounty. I searched and found nothing. I think the answer is "no," as you've defined it.